# how to set -fx-graphic size in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

[image]I create a button with -fx-graphic CSS,how to set -fx-graphic size in JavaFX?

I try to use  `-fx-max-height: 50; -fx-max-width: 50;` but it didn't work.

the image is too large.

```
        Button deleteButton = new Button();
            deleteButton.getStyleClass().add("delete-button");
```

```css
.delete-button {
    -fx-graphic: url(../view/Close.png);
    -fx-max-height: 50;
    -fx-max-width: 50;
}
```

Comment: Why not use a smaller image (which will also consume less memory)?

Comment: Because the graphics look really bad.@Slaw

Comment: Did you have a Look at [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35866168/javafx-css-button-graphic-resize) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to manage your graphic size from CSS, but you can do it programmatically instead,

```
Button deleteButton = new Button();

ImageView image = new ImageView(new Image("../view/Close.png"));
image.setFitWidth(50);
image.setFitHeight(50);

deleteButton.setGraphic(image);
```

> **Alternatively,**

You can set a background image on your button altenatively,

```
.deleteButton {
    -fx-background-image: url(../view/Close.png);
    -fx-background-size: 50px 50px;
    -fx-background-position: center;
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Or

```
BackgroundSize size = new BackgroundSize(
        50,
        50,
        true,
        true,
        true,
        false);
BackgroundImage image = new BackgroundImage(new Image("../view/Close.png"),
        BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT,
        BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT,
        BackgroundPosition.CENTER,
        size);

deleteButton.setBackground(new Background(image));
```